# adb connect to android emulator from virtualbox windows os

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, virtualbox

On my Windows 7 host system I have a virtualbox with Windows 7 as guest.

My goal is to work with android emulator (running at host) from virtual machine. I setted the next port forwarding settings (see the picture below).
[vm port forwarding settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQe7k.png)

Unfortunately the next cmd:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:5554
```

Gives me the next output:

```
unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:5554: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5554: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

Also, if I use real ip of my host Windows system (ethernet interface):

```
C:\Users\windows>adb connect 106.125.38.92:5554
connected to 106.125.38.92:5554
```

But **adb devices** gives me that android emulator device is offline:

```
C:\Users\windows>adb devices
List of devices attached
106.125.38.92:5554      offline
```

What steps I missed ?

Comment: did you try to run: `adb forward tcp:5554 tcp:5554` ?

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin
No I haven't. I need to execute this command from virtual machine ? Or at  the host system ?

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin received the next output
C:\windows\system32>adb forward tcp:5554 tcp:5554
error: cannot bind listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5554: Only one usage of ea
ch socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)

Comment: so try to use port `10048 `

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin, sorry but I don't understand how it will solve my problem. I know that emulator uses 5554 and 5555 ports. How your proposal would help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution for my problem.

I have installed Android x86 virtual machine in VBox (with image from https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/).

Attached both of the Windows vm and Android vm to NatNetwork (previously created).

```
windows eth0 10.0.2.4
android eth0 10.0.2.5
```

As a result, adb connect from Windows vm to Android vm works fine.

```
C:\>adb connect 10.0.2.5:5555
connected to 10.0.2.5:5555
C:\>adb devices
List of devices attached
10.0.2.5:5555   device
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you fix this? How did you set up "NatNetwork" ?

Comment: Go to the VirtualBox application settings (preferences) then choose Network tab and create it by "Adds new NAT network" button. After that, you will be able to select created NAT network in the VM's settings.

Comment: In my case I am not getting eth0 details on Android when firing `ifconfig`. 
It just gives me local loopback `lo` details..
I am at same situation like yours with just a difference of Ubuntu VM instead of Windows VM.

Comment: Do we have to do any specific download from osboxes.org/android-x86? 
I tried downloading and installing 2 to 3 Android VMs and all are having this same problem of missing eth0. Upon firing `ifconfig`, I just get only one interface. :(